# Restructure Attendance Table Logic

Tags: c#, sql-server

Attendance Table

```
 id | rollno  | faculty | date       | PresentAbsent
 ---|---------|---------|------------|--------------
  1 |  RP1201 | ABC     | 12/12/2016 | P
  2 |  RP1202 | ABC     | 12/12/2016 | A
```

Leave Table

```
  Lid | rollno | startdate  | enddate    | full-half-day | time
  ----|--------|------------|------------|---------------|---------------
    1 | RP1201 | 11/12/2016 | 12/12/2016 | fullday       | Not applicable
    2 | RP1202 | 12/12/2016 | 12/12/2016 | halfday       | 10.30-11.30
```

Required  Report

```
rollno | totallecture | totalpresent | totalabsent | totalleave | withoutLeave% | withLeave%
-------|--------------|--------------|-------------|------------|---------------|-----------
RP1201 | 12           | 6            | 6           | 2          | 50%           | 66.66%
```

From above table logic at the starting it works fine but table entry increase it takes more time to calculate report.

> Please help me to change table logic which help me to execute report
>   in few second

Please any other suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: You can add one more column to count number of days present each month.

Comment: @Prajwal  thanks for reply  in which table

Comment: You might have to change the entire structure.

Comment: Please Guide me I thought different way but still not get proper way because so many condition like some time leave put before Attendance sometime later  sometime time attendance may change at then end of term etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your `Leave` table, use a `trigger`. Whenever there is a new Leave inserted, this trigger will update the `Attendance` table for `PresentAbsent=A`with `FD` or `HD`.
2. Now while creating report, consider these `FD` and `HD` to calculate the `TotalAbsent` and `TotalLeave`.

If you are able to figure out the report query, this addition will do some modification on it. Hope I am clear. Let me know in comments if you have any question.

Comment: ok i will try your solution but sometime leave may be more than one month it will not be showing speed problem

Comment: Trigger performance might be bit slow if you are using Index in `attendance` table, but it is a one time thing for each leave.

I would suggest you to create this or any other structure and try with some sample data so you can see the performance yourself. Also in your original query, use index if you are not already.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this.

Create **Leave table**, with total number of days for leave. For half day, it can be 0.5 which uses roll number are foreign key.
Something like this

```
  Lid | rollno | startdate  | enddate    | full-half-day | time          |numberofdays
  ----|--------|------------|------------|---------------|---------------|------------
    1 | RP1201 | 11/12/2016 | 12/12/2016 | fullday       | Not applicable|2
    2 | RP1202 | 12/12/2016 | 12/12/2016 | halfday       | 10.30-11.30   |0.5
```

After that query it like this (I'm writing a pseudo code).

```
select sum(days-of-leave) from LeaveTable where rollnumber=rp1001
```

for total absent and present do this.

```
select count(presentabsent) as absent from attendence
where rollnumber=rp1001 and presentabsent=A
```